# How to stop audio in background mode?

Tags: ios

I want to stop audio in background mode in first controller and play audio in background mode in second controller.

I use this code:

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mp3",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"sound"];
 NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
 _player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
 _player.numberOfLoops = 1000;
 [_player play];
```

To stop audio in background mode I use this code:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: NO error: nil];
```

To play audio in background mode I use this code:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
```

But my code to stop audio doesn't work...

**UPD**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleForgroundScenario) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
    [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleBackgroundScenario) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter removeObserver:self];
}

-(void) handleForgroundScenario {
    if([self.player rate] == 0) {
        [_player play];
    }
}

-(void) handleBackgroundScenario {
    [_player pause];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
     setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
     error: nil];

    [super viewDidLoad];

         NSString *soundFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mp3",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"sound"];
         NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
         _player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
         _player.numberOfLoops = 1000;
         [_player play];
}
```

Comment: What exactly happens? In all tutorials regarding SO you will read that "doesn't work" is a very bad problem description. So you might want to read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't see _any_ code to stop your audio. You would need to tell the `_player` to stop, and I don't see you doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ApplicationWillResign notification in ViewWillAppear of ViewController in which you wanna pause player

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleBackgroundScenario), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)
   }
```

Pause player in selector

```
@objc func handleBackgroundScenario() {
    //pause
}
```

Finally remove observer in viewWillDisappear

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

This will make sure that notification will be triggered only when ViewController is loaded and app goes to background.

For all other VC notification will not trigger the selector and hence it will not alter the behavior of player

**EDIT:**

Code in Objective - C

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleBackgroundScenario) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
}

-(void) handleBackgroundScenario {
   //pause player
   [_player pause];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter removeObserver:self];
}
```

**EDIT:**

> Where I should call player after app become alive?

By the statement u mean when to start player when app comes to foreground you can use

```
[NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleForgroundScenario) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

Finally implement `handleForgroundScenario`

```
-(void) handleForgroundScenario {
    if([self.player rate] == 0) {
        [_player play];
    }
}
```

Comment: Where I should call player after app become alive?

Comment: Where I should use `[NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleForgroundScenario) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];`?

Comment: @user : In viewWillAppear along with UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification

Comment: I add code in question in **UPD**. If I use this code my audio stops if I hide app. But If app comes to foreground my audio not play.

Comment: Please check the updated answer see the usage of UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification rather than using willEnterForeground notification this should solve your problem

Comment: In my code in I change `[NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleForgroundScenario) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];` on `[NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleForgroundScenario) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];` But it not work...

Comment: @user : Can you please add a break point in handleForgroundScenario method and check if control enters this function when app is launched from background. If yes, then may be the condition if([self.player rate] == 0) { is wrong thats all

Comment: @user : hahahaha u have the solution then check why is that wrong and ur code will work fine buddy :) Your initial question is answered as to how to pause audio player when app goes to background :) Check if avplayer instance is nil I think in your case it is if thats the case create a property of AVPlayer now you are using a local variable inside ViewDidLoad hope it helps if need help lemme know

Comment: @user : Please consider accepting the answer if it helped

Comment: I will accept answer. It its work. But in this case after app comes to foreground my audio start playing again but need to audio continue play in pause point.

Comment: @user : This is a very common question you will find multiple answer for it in SO buddy you can try searching in SO in case u cant find solution u can raise another question with what you have tried and we will help u out

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @user : You are always welcome buddy :) AM glad I could be of some help :) Don't worry about the other thing u asked raise a question with proper code of what have you tried so far and we will help u out but before doing so search SO for the similar question am pretty sure there are many answers :) Hope u find answer soon :) Cheers